# PHP convert nested array to single array while concatenating parent name?

Tags: php, arrays

I am exporting Ebay all category and i want to store it in my database so i would display it in dropdown later.

Here is an example array:

```
$foo = array(
    0 => array(
        ['category'] => array(
            ['categoryId'] => 1,
            ['categoryName'] => 'Collectables'
        ),
        ['child'] => array(
            0 => array(
                ['category'] => array(
                    ['category'] => array(
                        ['categoryId'] => 34,
                        ['categoryName'] => 'Advertising'
                    ),
                    ['child'] => array(
                        0 => array(
                            ['category'] => array(
                                ['categoryId'] => 35,
                                ['categoryName'] => 'Other Advertising'
                            ),
                        ),
                        1 => array(
                            ['category'] => array(
                                ['categoryId'] => 36,
                                ['categoryName'] => 'Drinks'
                            ),
                            ['child'] => array(
                                0 => array(
                                    ['category'] => array(
                                        ['categoryId'] => 13601,
                                        ['categoryName'] => 'Coca Cola'
                                    ),
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            ),
        )
    ),
    1 => array(
        ['category'] => array(
            ['categoryId'] => 99,
            ['categoryName'] => 'Everything Else'
        ),
        ['child'] => array(
            0 => array(
                ['category'] => array(
                    ['categoryId'] => 3133,
                    ['categoryName'] => 'Educational'
                ),
            ),
            1 => array(
                ['category'] => array(
                    ['categoryId'] => 14112,
                    ['categoryName'] => 'Test Auctions'
                ),
                ['child'] => array(
                    0 => array(
                        ['category'] => array(
                            ['categoryId'] => 37558,
                            ['categoryName'] => 'Attributes1'
                        ),
                    ),
                    1 => array(
                        ['category'] => array(
                            ['categoryId'] => 37561,
                            ['categoryName'] => 'Attributes4'
                        ),
                    ),
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

And I would like to get a result like this:

```
$result = array(
    0 => array(
        ['categoryId'] => 1,
        ['categoryName'] => 'Collectables'
    ),
    1 => array(
        ['categoryId'] => 34,
        ['categoryName'] => 'Collectables => Advertising'
    ),
    2 => array(
        ['categoryName'] => 35,
        ['categoryId'] => "Collectables => Advertising => Other Advertising",
    ),
    3 => array(
        ['categoryName'] => 36,
        ['categoryId'] => "Collectables => Advertising => Drinks ",
    ),
    4 => array(
        ['categoryName'] => 13601,
        ['categoryId'] => "Collectables => Advertising => Drinks => Coca Cola",
    ),
    5 => array(
        ['categoryName'] => 99,
        ['categoryId'] => "Everything Else",
    ),
    6 => array(
        ['categoryName'] => 3133,
        ['categoryId'] => "Everything Else => Educational",
    ),
);
```

and so on till all the child of array.
How would I go about writing a recursive function of PHP array to handle this?
Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your array structure sometimes `[category , child ]`, sometimes `[category => [category , child ]]`. If save only the 1st case, code below will work

```
function make($arr, $prefix='') { 
   $res = [];
   if ($prefix) $prefix .= ' => ';
   foreach($arr as $x) {
      $x['category']['categoryName'] = $prefix . $x['category']['categoryName'];
      $res[] = $x['category'];   
      if (isset($x['child'])) {
        $res = array_merge($res,  make($x['child'], $x['category']['categoryName']));
      }
   }   
   return $res;
}

make($foo);
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/911629)

Comment: I am using this. can you convert this response to my response.

https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/commerce/taxonomy/resources/category_tree/methods/getCategoryTree#h2-samples

Comment: I also change the array structure and its `[category , child ]`

Comment: I don't see any change in the array. Show valid array by var_export or put it on eval.in

Comment: Add `<?` before array - Fatal error: Illegal offset type in /tmp/execpad-d4806e8da550/source-d4806e8da550 on line 38 - https://eval.in/912270

Comment: i didn't get any error in https://eval.in/911913 and please can you give me solution for my array as i mention in above link.